# Android justifying android text

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I am trying to make sure that the hours are all justified (meaning they begin and end at the same margin) as you can see from Monday-Thursday they align properly. Friday and Saturday the 11:00 is not aligned properly with the rest. No doubt because of the 03:00 and 01:00 taking different amount of space. But is there a way to make them all align perfectly?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_3times"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >
    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_day"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:text="Day"/>
    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:text="Hour"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: hours unaligned]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a monospaced font. Monospaced font use fixed width sizes for each character. Android has Droids Sans Mono that you can use.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_3times"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >
    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_day"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:text="Day"/>
    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:text="Hour"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would like to try this without using monospace since the company I am working for is a bit picky. Is there another way to do this to get full justification?

Comment: I ended up installing DroidsansMono font and importing it in to my project for future use as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_3times" >

    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_day"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:text="Day" />

    <com.example.views.TextView
        android:id="@+id/openhour_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_size"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hour" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can play around with the layout_weight values in both TextViews to get it exactly the way you want. In this example, the width assigned to "Day" will be twice what gets assigned to "Hour".

Comment: It would have taken a while for me to get the solution to work so I went with user2453771 suggestion. Plus i tried for a while with little success.

Answer (score 0):

```
app Grandle : compile 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

Text View code :
 <me.biubiubiu.justifytext.library.JustifyTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```